# React, I cant seem to turn each movieID into the movieId's provider Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

[Sandbox React Project](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-hill-m4g4f?file=/src/App.js)

So I have an list of Movie ID's displayed that were fetched from an API.  I also was able to call another API endpoint to get the movies provider link but using the MOVIE ID as a parameter in another fetch call.  I was able to display one  of the movie ID"s links.  As you can see in this sandbox in the browser I was able to return ONE link.  But i need the rest of the links that belong to the other movie ID's.  Im having trouble getting this to work though, I was only able to display one.
I put the code down below but I recommend checking out the sandbox to see exactly what I mean.

```
    import "./styles.css";
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { render } from "react-dom";
    
    const getMovieDetail = (movieId) => {
      const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}/watch/providers?api_key=fde5ddeba3b7dec3fc1f51852ca0fb95`;
      return fetch(url);
    };
    
    function MovieDetail(props) {
      const [movie, setMovie] = useState(null);
      const { id } = props;
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getMovieDetail(id)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((res) => setMovie(res.results.US.link));
      }, [id]);
    
      return movie ? (
        <code>{JSON.stringify(movie)}</code>
      ) : (
        <p>Probably fetching data</p>
      );
    }
    
    export default function App() {
      const [trending, setTrending] = useState([]);
    
      //set movieID to get the movie ID's
    
      //set link to get the providerlink that belongs to each movieID.
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const trendUrl =
          "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=fde5ddeba3b7dec3fc1f51852ca0fb95";
        fetch(trendUrl)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setTrending(data.results);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error!! Data interupted!:", error);
          });
      }, []);
    
      const moviesIdCollections = trending.map((item) => item.id);
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
          <MovieDetail id={moviesIdCollections} />
          {moviesIdCollections.map((elm) => (
            <p key={elm}>{elm}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const getMovieDetail = (movieId) => {
  const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}/watch/providers?api_key=fde5ddeba3b7dec3fc1f51852ca0fb95`;

  return fetch(url);
};

function MovieDetail({id}) {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(id);
    getMovieDetail(id)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setMovie(res?.results?.US?.link));
  }, [id]);

  return movie ? (
    <code>{JSON.stringify(movie)}</code>
  ) : (
    <p>Probably fetching data</p>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [trending, setTrending] = useState([]);

  //set movieID to get the movie ID's

  //set link to get the providerlink that belongs to each movieID.

  useEffect(() => {
    const trendUrl =
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=fde5ddeba3b7dec3fc1f51852ca0fb95";
    fetch(trendUrl)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setTrending(data.results);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error!! Data interupted!:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  const moviesIdCollections = trending.map((item) => item.id);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      {moviesIdCollections.map((elm) => (
        <>
          {" "}
          <MovieDetail id={elm} />
          <p key={elm}>{elm}</p>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You need to push MovieDetail in moviesIdCollections.map so it able to display all the movie link

Comment: THANK YOU! ive been trying like crazy to get this for the past few days without any luck!

Comment: What is up with the ?   setMovie(res?.results?.US?.link));   and why doesnt it work without the question marks?>

Comment: `?` It's just making sure objects have a valid value. If res?.results don't have results it will still be valid to compiler

Answer (score 0):

I think compiler complains about type of data. you can check by adding ? mark.

```
function MovieDetail(props) {
  //...
  useEffect(() => {
    getMovieDetail(id)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setMovie(res?.results?.US?.link));
  }, [id]);
 //...
}
```

Comment: All im trying to do is run each one of those MovieID's thorugh "getmovieDetail"  and "movieDetal" functions to get each ones link.  as displayed on the very top.

Comment: It's javascript grammer that check existance.  same with
    setMovie(res && res.results && res.results.US && res.results.US.link)

Comment: It just not adding up in my head though with the setMovie(res?.results?.US?.link);   so its saying  setMovie(if res, if results if US if link?